# Problems with Symbian descriptor assignment

Tags: c++, symbian, descriptor

Once again I am struggeling with Symbians Descriptors...

```
char fileName[128] = "somethingsomething";
```

Next I have then en TEntry object which has a member iName. To this iName
I would like to assign my fileName. I tried to do it as follows:

```
TEntry anEntry;

anEntry.iName.Copy((TText8* )rEntity->fileName);
```

-

```
no instance of overloaded function " TBufC::Copy [with S=256]" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (TText8 *)
        object type is: TBufC<256>
                    anEntry.iName.Copy((TText8* )rEntity->fileName);
```

Do I need to use another function to copy the filename into entry.iname?

Many thanks

Comment: I am no convinced this is a descriptor issue. What do you plan on doing with the TEntry object?

Answer (score 1):

TBufC is non-modifiable (C is for "constant"). It doesn't have any Copy functions.

http://developer.symbian.com/main/documentation/sdl/symbian94/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/E32_EKA2/TBufCClass.html

Try something like:

```
iName.Des().Copy(TPtrC8((TText8*)fileName));
```

or

```
TBuf<256> tmp;  // or HBuf if you're worried about using so much stack
tmp.Copy(TPtrC8((TText8*)filename));
iName = tmp;
```

If you can't change the type of iName, maybe you can change fileName to be stored in a descriptor instead of just a char array? As you've discovered, mixing the two is painful.

This all assumes that your 8-bit char is ascii or ISO-latin, not UTF-8. If the latter, you need to convert the character encoding as well.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. However, the problem is that I am trying to implement some interface, so I am NOT able to change the type of the iName data member. Is there any way I can somehow assign the filename with casting to constant maybe :P

Comment: You can use operator= on TBufC. I'm a bit rusty, but try something like iName = TPtrC8(fileName). Note that you can instead call Des() on a TBufC to get a modifiable descriptor, which you can then call Copy on.

Comment: Thanks for this onebyone. iName = TPtrC8(fileName) does unfortunately not work. However, I should say that fileName is not a constant char as it changes during program execution. Hope that is not a problem I can still assign it somehow to this TBufC variable!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the zero-terminated `const char []` data in a `TPtrC` to make it a descriptor that can be passed to `Copy`. However, `TEntry::iName` is a constant `TBufC` but you can call `Des` on it to get a modifiable `TPtr`:

```
anEntry.iName.Des().Copy(TPtrC8((TText8 *)rEntity->fileName));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem remains the same... Is it possible that this iName member has no Copy method although its from type TBufC as the description outlines:

  TBufC< KMaxFileName > iName;
  The name of the file relative to the owning directory, with a maximum of KMaxFileName characters.

Comment: anEntry.iName = _L("Test"); This here works... drives me mad the descriptors. Is there maybe something like a strcpy in Symbian without using the stdlib?

Comment: Yes.. Something like `strcpy` is `TDes::Copy`. I've updated my answer to cater for the fact that TEntry::iName is a const `TBufC`.